# pygame.surface object not callable

Tags: pygame

I'm making a a paint project, but I'm having some errors using the ellipse tool. The error is *"TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable."*  I have all the variables defined, it's just giving me an error on this line: ball=Rect(startx,starty,mx-startx,my-starty).

```
if tool == "ellipse":

    if mb[0]== 1:
            screen.blit(copy,(0,0))

            ball=Rect(startx,starty,mx-startx,my-starty)

            ball.normalize()

            if ball.width < size*2 or ball.height < size*2:

                    screen.blit(copy,(0,0))
                    draw.ellipse(screen,dracolour,ball,0)
            else:
                    screen.blit(copy,(0,0))  
                    draw.ellipse(screen,drawcolour,ball,size)
```

Comment: It is poor form to use desperate begging language such as "need help fast" and "my project is due soon!"  Fortunately, I've cleaned up your question in that regard.

Comment: But Barney,do you the solotuin for my problem?

Comment: You should use the "@name" notation to refer to people - Barney would not have seen a notification of this message.  As for me, I have a vague idea of what might cause this sort of error, but it would require a more properly worded and detailed question, and in crafting such, you will likely be able to determine the answer for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error:

> TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable.

on this line:

```
ball=Rect(startx,starty,mx-startx,my-starty)
```

this means you have hidden the `pygame.Rect` class with an instance of `pygame.Surface`.

Look at your code where you asign a `Surface` to `Rect` (something like `Rect=...something...`) and choose another variable name.

Comment: Thank you my problem is fixed.